# Why do I need to set yarn.application.classpath on client side, when classpath is already set on cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am submitting a Spark job with `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster` to an EMR cluster on AWS, from a node outside the cluster.

The job has dependencies on the AWS SDK for S3.

I get `ClassNotFoundException` on `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`, unless I also set `yarn.application.classpath` in `yarn-site.xml`,  on the *client* side (where I'm calling spark-submit).  If I copy-paste this setting from the `yarn-site.xml` on the EMR cluster master node, it works.

What I don't understand is why I need to do this: if the cluster is already configured with this classpath, why do I also need to configure this property from the client side?  Especially because all the paths refer to folders that live on the EMR cluster, not the client.